# Generate records between STN and ACT prod_day range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following table showing switching status of motor, standing and active:

```
Name    prod_day    daytime             status
T105    25/Dec/11   25/Dec/11 21:00:00  STN
T105    01/Jan/12   01/Jan/12 02:28:00  ACT
T105    17/Apr/12   17/Apr/12 16:14:00  STN
T105    01/Jun/12   01/Jun/12 03:30:00  ACT
T7      30/Dec/11   30/Dec/11 14:00:00  ACT
T7      02/Jan/12   02/Jan/12 09:12:00  STN
T7      07/Jan/12   07/Jan/12 16:30:00  ACT
T7      07/May/12   07/May/12 01:06:00  STN
```

What I need is to generate following records(in select query) between STN and ACT prod_day range and  Start daytime              of next status is going to be End_daytime  for previous status and etc, see example:

```
Name        prod_day    Start_daytime          End_daytime                   Status
T105        01/Jan/12   01/Jan/12 02:28:00                                    ACT
T105        02/Jan/12   01/Jan/12 02:28:00                                    ACT
T105        03/Jan/12   01/Jan/12 02:28:00                                    ACT
T105        17/Apr/12   01/Jan/12 02:28:00     17/Apr/12 16:14:00             ACT
T105        17/Apr/12   17/Apr/12 16:14:00                                    STN
T105        18/Apr/12   17/Apr/12 16:14:00                                    STN
T105        19/Apr/12   17/Apr/12 16:14:00                                    STN
T105        01/Jun/12   17/Apr/12 16:14:00     01/Jun/12 03:30:00             STN
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you post the sql which you are working on

Comment: so far I don't have the sql query, I tried various option but no success, not sure how realize it in sql.

Comment: Not sure how to interpret your data. you have ACT starting on 1stJan then switching to STN on 17thApr but your output also shows records for the 2nd and 3rd that don't appear in the input. you show the first 3 days of a new period of ACT or STN when it changes ?

Comment: I just showed few days here since showing all till 17thApr here is not good idea, yea normally it has to be all days till status is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this hierarchical query:

```
with t as (select name, daytime, status,  
                  row_number() over (partition by name order by daytime) rn,
                  lead(daytime) over (partition by name order by daytime) ldt,
                  lead(daytime) over (partition by name order by daytime) - daytime ndt
             from motor)
select rn, level, name, trunc(daytime + level - 1) prod_day, daytime + level - 1 sdt, 
       case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then ldt end edt, status
  from t
  connect by prior rn = rn and prior name = name and level - 1 <= ndt 
         and prior sys_guid() is not null
  order by name , rn, sdt
```

In column `ndt` I'm counting how many times we have to add one day to starting `daytime`, it's then compared with pseudocolumn `level`. Condition `prior sysquid...` is sometimes used in hierarchical queries to avoid cycling.

Test data:

```
create table motor (Name varchar2(5), prod_day date, daytime date, status varchar2(4));
insert into motor values ('T105', date '2011-12-25', timestamp '2011-12-25 21:00:00', 'STN');
insert into motor values ('T105', date '2012-01-01', timestamp '2012-01-01 02:28:00', 'ACT');
insert into motor values ('T105', date '2012-04-17', timestamp '2012-04-17 16:14:00', 'STN');
insert into motor values ('T105', date '2012-06-01', timestamp '2012-06-01 03:30:00', 'ACT');
insert into motor values ('T7',   date '2011-12-30', timestamp '2011-12-30 14:00:00', 'ACT');
insert into motor values ('T7',   date '2012-01-02', timestamp '2012-01-02 09:12:00', 'STN');
insert into motor values ('T7',   date '2012-01-07', timestamp '2012-01-07 16:30:00', 'ACT');
insert into motor values ('T7',   date '2012-05-07', timestamp '2012-05-07 01:06:00', 'STN');
```

Output:

```
        RN      LEVEL NAME  PROD_DAY    SDT                 EDT                 STATUS
---------- ---------- ----- ----------- ------------------- ------------------- ------
         1          1 T105  2011-12-25  2011-12-25 21:00:00                     STN
         1          2 T105  2011-12-26  2011-12-26 21:00:00                     STN
         1          3 T105  2011-12-27  2011-12-27 21:00:00                     STN
       ...
         1          7 T105  2011-12-31  2011-12-31 21:00:00 2012-01-01 02:28:00 STN
         2          1 T105  2012-01-01  2012-01-01 02:28:00                     ACT
         2          2 T105  2012-01-02  2012-01-02 02:28:00                     ACT
         2          3 T105  2012-01-03  2012-01-03 02:28:00                     ACT
       ...
         2        108 T105  2012-04-17  2012-04-17 02:28:00 2012-04-17 16:14:00 ACT
         3          1 T105  2012-04-17  2012-04-17 16:14:00                     STN
         3          2 T105  2012-04-18  2012-04-18 16:14:00                     STN
         3          3 T105  2012-04-19  2012-04-19 16:14:00                     STN
       ...  
         3         45 T105  2012-05-31  2012-05-31 16:14:00 2012-06-01 03:30:00 STN
         4          1 T105  2012-06-01  2012-06-01 03:30:00                     ACT
         1          1 T7    2011-12-30  2011-12-30 14:00:00                     ACT
         1          2 T7    2011-12-31  2011-12-31 14:00:00                     ACT
         1          3 T7    2012-01-01  2012-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-02 09:12:00 ACT
         2          1 T7    2012-01-02  2012-01-02 09:12:00                     STN
         2          2 T7    2012-01-03  2012-01-03 09:12:00                     STN
         2          3 T7    2012-01-04  2012-01-04 09:12:00                     STN
       ...
         2          6 T7    2012-01-07  2012-01-07 09:12:00 2012-01-07 16:30:00 STN
         3          1 T7    2012-01-07  2012-01-07 16:30:00                     ACT
         3          2 T7    2012-01-08  2012-01-08 16:30:00                     ACT
         3          3 T7    2012-01-09  2012-01-09 16:30:00                     ACT
       ...
         3        121 T7    2012-05-06  2012-05-06 16:30:00 2012-05-07 01:06:00 ACT
         4          1 T7    2012-05-07  2012-05-07 01:06:00                     STN

292 rows selected
```